# importStyleSheet function PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xls

I'm trying to run the function importStyleSheet but I've a warning when I run my function :

- Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given
  The path to my files are corrects.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$xsl = $xsl->load("E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xsl");

$xslt = new xsltProcessor();
$xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$xmldoc->load(file_get_contents("E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xml"));
print $xslt->transformToXML($xmldoc);
?>
```

Here is my xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As an aside, giving parameters to the `DOMDocument` constructor is useless since they are always overwritten by `DOMDocument::load` method. `$xsl = new DOMDocument;` suffices.

Comment: Not sure you can access this absolute URL with `DOMDocument::load` from a php file located on your server. Use a relative URL instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the 2nd line

```
$xsl = $xsl->load("E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xsl");
```

replace that with

```
$xsl->load("E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xsl");
```

The `load` method returns a `boolean` so you have, at that point, changed `$xsl` into the boolean result rather than the reference to `DOMDocument`

You might also want to change

```
$xmldoc->load(file_get_contents("E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xml"));
```

to

```
$xmldoc->load( "E:/wamp64/www/structuration/test.xml" );
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't see this small mistake !!